# SQL Spark sum and group multiple columns

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I have a table with column "customerId" and column "classification in: weekly buyer, monthly buyer and yearly buyer".

The  classification condition on basis of order days between last order has already been done.

```
select customerId,  dayofyear(date) - lag(dayofyear(date)) over(partition by customerId order by date) as Differenz, 
case when (dayofyear(date) - lag(dayofyear(date)) over(partition by customerId order by date)) <= 9 then "weekly buyer"
      when (dayofyear(date) - lag(dayofyear(date)) over(partition by customerId order by date)) between 10 and 19 then "every two weeks"
      when (dayofyear(date) - lag(dayofyear(date)) over(partition by customerId order by date)) between 20 and 40 then "monthly buyer"
      when (dayofyear(date) - lag(dayofyear(date)) over(partition by customerId order by date)) > 40 then "occastional buyer"
      else null
      end as Einstufung
from orders 
order by customerId, date
```

I want to find out whether the customer is at the end a weekly, every two weeks,monthly or occastional buyer.

Customers can order multiple times, so that customerId = 1 orders weekly, weekly and monthly. So in sum he is a weaely buyer. How can I define this in sql?

I simplified the table in excel:

[image]